# Command to switch current focus between monitors

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, xdotools

I have some scripts which depend on the current monitor focus and want a key binding that toggles the current focus between monitors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use `xrandr` (`-q` gives the list of monitors):

> - External only:
>   `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --output LVDS1 --off`
> - Extended left, internal primary: `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --output LVDS1 --auto --primary`
> - Extended left, external primary: `xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 --primary --output LVDS1 --auto`
> - Internal only: `xrandr --output VGA1 --off --output LVDS1 --auto`

Source: [Switch monitors from the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/155004/switch-monitors-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I don't want to turn the monitor off. I just want to toggle the focus between the two.